# What is lambda in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain the concept of a lambda in Ruby 2.0? Where we can use lambdas? How is it useful in a project? Merits and Demerits?

Please explain in real time use ?

Comment: This is a very poor question.  If you had done any research at all you'd know what a lambda is.  @Daniel has pointed you to two articles that are both quite good.  The first, however, is at the top of the list when Googling "Ruby lambda".

Comment: I am new to ruby that's why i asked if you feel bad sorry.

Comment: This is a question for google

Comment: Your question has not made me feel bad.  My concern is that this is not an efficient way for you to learn.  You should first do the research, then post questions when you hit a roadblock or require clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambda has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails, it is a Ruby construct.
To be short, in Ruby most of the situations where other languages use anonymous functions are handled with blocks. However, blocks cannot be stored for later use so when you need to store it, you can choose to use a lambda to do so.

For further explanations, check out [this post](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/).

Comment: I would also recommend [this post](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/ruby-procs-and-lambdas-and-the-difference-between-them/).